# How to generate below query using elasticsearch java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregate

I want to generate similar query using Elasticsearch JAVA API . I am trying to apply filters at an aggregation level.

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{ "terms":{ "family_name":"Brown" } } //filter_1
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "filter":{
                "terms" : {
                   "gender" : "male" //filter_2
                 } 
            },
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the sample code that i am up to

```
TermFilterBuilder family_filter_1 = FilterBuilders.termFilter("family_name","Brown");

FilteredQueryBuilder qbuilder =QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),family_filter_1);


SearchRequestBuilder search  = client.prepareSearch("test_index")
.setTypes("test_type")
.setSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)
.setQuery(qbuilder);

search.addAggregation(terms("age").field("age") 
.size(0)// Size 0 returns all the "group by keys"
.order(Terms.Order.count(true))); // to sort the output 

System.out.println(""+search);
```

and response i am getting . Please suggest how to add filter_2

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "family_name" : "Brown"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "age" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "age",
        "size" : 0,
        "order" : {
          "_count" : "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're missing the name of the field on which the `range` filter aggregation is run, i.e. the field on which `filter_2` is run.

Comment: @val That's just for an example... Modified the question.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// same as your code
TermFilterBuilder family_filter_1 = ...;
FilteredQueryBuilder qbuilder = ...;
SearchRequestBuilder search = ...;

// build the range filter
RangeQuery ageRange = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age")
    .from(18).to(40).includeLower(false).includeUpper(false);

// build the terms sub-aggregation
TermsAggregation age = AggregationBuilders.terms("age")
    .field("age") 
    .size(0)
    .order(Terms.Order.count(true));

// build the filter top-aggregation
FilterAggregationBuilder youngAge = AggregationBuilders
    .filter("young_age")
    .filter(ageRange)
    .subAggregation(age);


search.addAggregation(youngAge);
```

Comment: Thanks for AggregationBuilders logic